# Google container engine : pod creation stuck in 'Pending' status

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Tried to recreate the GKE cluster to try on Kubernetes 1.2.0

Cluster came up correctly, yet the firs pod deployment is stuck in 'Pending':

```
[]# kubectl get pods
NAME            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
operation-daily   0/1       Pending   0          6m
```

Have been following the same script that was used for 1.1.8 (successfully).

Tried a few times - no luck.

How could I diagnose the issue? 
Would it be possible to go back to 1.1.8 version?

us-central-1f

Comment: In this particular case the issue was with the new resource limits introduced (?) with 1.2 version, preventing the pod from deployment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `kubectl get events` should have some clues for you.

Comment: Thank you. I got "Node didn't have enough resource: CPU, requested: 100, used: 920, capacity: 1000" That's for n1-standard-1 node hosting everything. Checked the load on the box and it is 15% tops. Is there a reason there were new resources limits were introduced? Fixed with limiting the cpu for the pod in the meantime.

Comment: It's presumably the cluster addons which were using the extra CPU on the machine. I believe that in version 1.1 not all of the addons explicitly reserved any CPU for themselves, which led to them sometimes not getting enough to function under load.

Out of curiosity, did you have any of your own pods running on the node or was it almost full from just the default system components?

Comment: All the pods were from the system. The pod that failed was the first custom pod. There were no limit defined on it (just a crond triggering a process somewhere else). Thus it got assigned 100 cpu by default and failed.