# GKE : Kubernetes 1.2.0 for single node deployment

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

It seems that with Kubernetes release 1.2.0 a single node deployment:

```
gcloud container clusters create "$CLUSTER_NAME" \
--machine-type "n1-standard-1" \
--num-nodes "1" \
```

does not leave much cpu headroom - the k8n pods claim 920 out of 1000 cpu points.

(My other question : [Google container engine : pod creation stuck in 'Pending' status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170140/google-container-engine-pod-creation-stuck-in-pending-status))

Is it a conscious decision?

Is there a way to adjust it, as I do not see the need for such limit in my case (CPU does not exceed 15%) and I would like to avoid getting a larger machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same issue, already on 1.1.8.
I solved it by removing most pods in the kube-system namespace
(kubectl --namespace=kube-system get po)
and adjusting resources on my own RC.

End result, I have 10 pods running on 1 f1-micro...

I would not recommend that for a prod environment though.

Comment: Not sure I am (yet) bold enough to do that, but thank you for the idea. In the meantime - would it be possible to reassign the weights of the pods?

Comment: You mean the kube-system pods?

Comment: If you mean your own pods, yes, you can, by adjusting the resources within the kubefiles YAML

`
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ReplicationController
    metadata:
      labels: {name: xxx}
      name: xxx
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector: {name: xxx}
      template:
        metadata:
          labels: {name: xxx}
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: xxx
            name: xxx
            ports:
            - {containerPort: 80, name: webui}
            resources:
              limits: {cpu: 60m, memory: 256Mi}
              requests: {cpu: 60m, memory: 100Mi}
`

Comment: Yes, kube-system pods. Preferably after they have been created (I would like to avoid mingling with the system set up).